# Javascript variable scope when adding function to array

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using TinyMCE 4 and trying to build a dynamic menu. In order to do this I am building an array of menu items which includes an onclick function. The menu displays, but the onclick function does not work because when building the array, the value I need to pass to the function is out of scope - I believe.

```
var MenuItems = [{"Id":"1","Name":"MenuItem 1"},{"Id":"2","Name":"MenuItem 2"}];

var Menu = [];
for (var i=0;i<MenuItems.length;i++)
{
    Menu.push({
        text: MenuItems[i].Name,
        onclick: function(){              
            alert(MenuItems[i].Id);
        }
    });
}
```

In the onclick declaration, MenuItems[i].Id is not in scope - I believe.

How can I pass the values to the onclick function.

I am then passing the array to the TinyMCE plugin, but I don't believe this is a problem with TinyMCE, but posting this part in case there is a better way.

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('myplugin', function(editor, url) {    
    editor.addButton('menu', {
        text: 'MyMenu',
        type: 'menubutton',
        icon: false,
        menu: Menu           
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MenuItems[]` won't be available when the callback for `myplugin` would run.

This would also mean, that once, `onclick` of any menuItem is called, it would try accessing `MenuItems[]`.

To fix this, once way could be to change the implementation like:

```
var MenuItems = [{"Id":"1","Name":"MenuItem 1"},{"Id":"2","Name":"MenuItem 2"}];

var Menu = [];
for (var i=0;i<MenuItems.length;i++)
{
    const id = MenuItems[i].Id;
    Menu.push({
        text: MenuItems[i].Name,
        onclick: function(){              
            alert(id);
        }
    });
}
```